# Check for cookie and then geo-redirect if

Tags: ajax, cookies, geo

The following geo-redirect code works:

```
<script async src="https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/geo.js"></script>
<script>
  function geoip() {
   $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/country.json',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data['country'] == "NZ") {
              window.location = "https://www.example.com/";
            }
        }
    });
    }
geoip();
</script>
```

Building on this, I now want to check for a cookie, but can't get it to work. Where am I going wrong?

```
<script async src="https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/geo.js"></script>
<script>
var cookieSwitch = 'geo-switch'; 
if(typeof Cookies.get(cookieSwitch) == 'undefined') { // If cookie is not found, then geo-redirect
  function geoip() {
   $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/country.json',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data['country'] == "NZ") {
              window.location = "https://www.example.com/";
            }
        }
    });
    }
geoip();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Would be really good if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked!

```
<script async src="https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/geo.js"></script>
<script>
if(typeof Cookies.get('geo-switch') == 'undefined') { // If cookie not found, then redirect if applicable
   $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/country.json',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data['country'] == "NZ") {
              window.location = "https://www.example.com/";
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Please note, you will need to include the following for this to work:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
```